# Recibir request desde urls.py

Tags: python, django, python-requests

En el sistema de activación de usuarios de mi plataforma, el usuario accede a un enlace de la siguiente forma:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/XSWEKklut8tzDdH/unemail@email.com/
```

Mi fichero **urls.py**

```
#home/urls.py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from home.views import homePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('',homePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
    re_path('activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/([\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', homePageView.activate, name='activate')
]
```

Mi método de la **views.py**

```
class homePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    def activate(self, request, code_, email_):
        try:
            user = Usuario.objects.get(email=email_,activated_code=code_)
            code = user.activated_code
            if (not user.activated) and code == code_:
                user.activated = True
                user.save()
                messages.success(request, 'User activated successfully')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'Error activating user, please, use the contact form to contact us')
        except Usuario.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request,'Error activating user, please, use the contact form to contact us')
        return redirect('home')
```

Y claro, como desde **urls.py** recibe dos parámetros y el método activate pide tres...

¿Cómo podría entonces hacer que el método reciba el request.

Gracias